sql difficulties counting one column and getting the oldest id with the same content
I'm making a school project in mvc .net core, where people should be able to send in a request for help and it will show on a screen, my difficulties comes with the part that other people should be able to want the same help, but I only want to show the request once with the oldest user id and be able to count how many people are having the same request.
Right now I'm using 3 tables

tableUser - which stores all the users information

helplist - which stores the description of the problem as well as some other information to send it to the right view

FH which stores the id from helplist and the user id to connect and make people request the same help from the helplist id


I've tried with the following SQL and I don't understand how I can get the oldest user id while counting the description,
SELECT Count (Beskrivning) AS HANTAL, Beskrivning, Hjalplista.HID
From ((FH INNER JOIN UserTable ON UserTable.UID = FH.UID)
      INNER JOIN Hjalplista ON Hjalplista.HID = FH.HID)
WHERE Hjalplista.KID = @KID AND Hstatus= 'Aktiv'
GROUP BY Beskrivning, Hjalplista.HID, FH.Fdatum
ORDER BY Fdatum ASC

Sorry for the Swedish, here's the "translated" version:
SELECT Count (Description) AS Hcount, Description, helplist.HID
From ((FH INNER JOIN UserTable ON UserTable.UID = FH.UID)
      INNER JOIN helplist ON helplist.HID = FH.HID)
WHERE helplist.KID = @KID AND Hstatus= 'Active'
GROUP BY Description, helplist.HID, FH.Fdate
ORDER BY Fdate ASC

(KID is used to select only the ones in the same view as someone is having on their screen)

You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to aggregate functions.

Which dbms are you using? (Access??? or why those nested joins?)

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to show some extra effort.

You can modify your SQL query to use a subquery to select the oldest user ID associated with each description. Then, you can join this subquery with your main query to filter out duplicate descriptions based on the oldest user ID. Here's how you can do it:
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Hcount,
    h.Description,
    h.HID
FROM 
    helplist AS h
INNER JOIN 
    FH AS f ON h.HID = f.HID
INNER JOIN 
    UserTable AS u ON f.UID = u.UID
WHERE 
    h.KID = @KID 
    AND h.Hstatus = 'Active' 
    AND f.Fdatum = (
        SELECT 
            MIN(Fdatum) 
        FROM 
            FH 
        WHERE 
            HID = h.HID
    )
GROUP BY 
    h.Description, h.HID

The crucial part is the subquery in the WHERE clause. This subquery selects the minimum (MIN) Fdatum associated with each HID, effectively giving us the oldest user ID for each description.
This query should give you the count of each unique description along with the oldest user ID associated with it.

I fixed it by doing this:
DataTable localtbl = new DataTable(); 
DataTable daTbl = new DataTable();
using SqlConnection connection = new(DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString);
using SqlConnection sqlCon = new(DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString);
{
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new("SELECT Distinct HID FROM Helplist Where KID = @KID", connection);
sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KID", id);
connection.Open();
 sqlDa.Fill(localtbl);


 

 for (int a = 0; a < localtbl.Rows.Count ; a++)
 {
     string query = "SELECT
(Select Count(FH.HID) FROM FH WHERE FH.HID = @HID and FStatus= 'Active') AS HAmount ,
 * FROM 
((FH INNER JOIN UserTable ON UserTable.UID = FH.UID)
 INNER JOIN Helplist ON Helplist.HID = FH.HID)
 where FH.UID = (SELECT UID FROM FH  WHERE HID = @HID AND FH.Fdate = 
(SELECT MIN(Fdate) FROM FH WHERE HID = @HID ) ) 
AND FH.HID = @HID order by Fdate ASC";

     SqlDataAdapter sqlDa2 = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon);
     sqlDa2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HID", localtbl.Rows[a]["HID"]);
     sqlDa2.Fill(daTbl);
 }
 daTbl.DefaultView.Sort = "Fdatum ASC";
 daTbl = daTbl.DefaultView.ToTable();
return View(daTbl)


While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.
